# Is this hadith authentic? Ibn Abbas

Tags: quran, hadith, isnad

Ibn 'Abbas said, "yuharrufuna" (4:46) means "they remove". No one removes the works of one of the Books of Allah Almighty, but they twist them, interpreting them improperly. "
Sahih Al Bukhari, Book of Tawhid, Hadith 55

Ibn Kathir also quotes this hadith in his commentary on Surah 4:147

I was told that it is not authentic because there is no Isnad, but it is just commentary on Surah 85:21-22

Comment: Ijtihad of ibn 'Abbas is strictly speaking not a hadith.

Comment: @Medi1Saif can we trust that Ibn Abbas said this? if so what is the reasoning without an isnad

Comment: I don't think that this statement was reported without isnad, at least at one of the sources like at-Tabari and ibn abi Hatim.